# Listbox items on canvas scaling on center

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, listbox

I'm trying to cobble together examples of listbox items on a (rendered via canvas) that expand in size when clicked.  I'm close but the items move when zoomed, I would like them to zoom from the center and stay in place.  Here is sample data collection.

```
public class Item
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsFactory
{
    private List<Item> items;
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items ?? (items = new List<Item>() 
            { 
                new Item { Name = "One", X = 100, Y = 100, Color="Red" },
                new Item { Name = "Two", X = 88, Y = 210, Color="Green" },
                new Item { Name = "Three", X = 200, Y = 295, Color="Blue" }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my WPF.  Items get bigger when clicked but they also move. I have tried `RenderTransformOrigin` in various places with no luck.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFCards.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFCards"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="395.268" Width="607.807" Background="Black" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ItemsFactory x:Key="sampleItems" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource sampleItems}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                 Background="Black"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple" >

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <Grid 
                            Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}">
                            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}" Width="50" Height="40" />
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Canvas>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <CubicEase x:Key="ease" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                            EasingFunction="{StaticResource ease}"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                            To="2"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                            EasingFunction="{StaticResource ease}"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                            To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`RenderTransform`** ***should be applied on ellipse container i.e. Grid*** and not on Canvas. Setting it on canvas is increasing the width and height of grid and hence affecting layout of ellipses in it.

Also, in case you want centric zoom, set `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` on Grid.

```
<Canvas>
   <Grid Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" 
         RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
      <Grid.RenderTransform>
         <ScaleTransform x:Name="st"
                         ScaleY="{Binding ScaleX,
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
      </Grid.RenderTransform>
      <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}" Width="50" Height="40" />
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
   </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of guessing: I think you should set

> RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"

of your Canvas